# MVC3 Razor with nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nunit

As a famous ORM we decided to user nHIbernate with asp.net mvc3. We set up our project in the following way:

1. NHibernate Repository [contains mappings, service and repositories for nhibernate]
2. MVC3 [this is a UI]
3. Test MVC NHibernate [this is a test project with NUnit]

In above, [] text are written ti make clear about the layers.

Everything is working fine, means all Unit Tests are passed for mapping, insert, update, delete operations. 
Unfotunately, when we are doing the same operation from our mvc3 application then it threw following error:

```
   "An exception occurred during configuration of persistence layer."
```

Full stack-trace is as follow:

```
   at NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration..ctor(XmlReader hbConfigurationReader, Boolean fromAppSetting) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\ConfigurationSchema\HibernateConfiguration.cs:line 55
   at NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration..ctor(XmlReader hbConfigurationReader) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\ConfigurationSchema\HibernateConfiguration.cs:line 36
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(XmlReader textReader) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1511
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(String fileName, Boolean ignoreSessionFactoryConfig) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1433
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(String fileName) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1418
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1404
   at examplemvcapp.NHibernateRepository..ctor() in D:\example\examplemvcapp-NHExample\examplemvcapp\NHibernateRepository.cs:line 33
   at examplemvcapp_NHExample.UI.Models.CreateAppraisalModel..ctor() in D:\example\examplemvcapp-NHExample\examplemvcapp-NHExample.UI\Models\Department.cs:line 70
```

Please note that all configuration settings for NHIbernate are same in MVC3 app as in Test project.

Following is the guy where we got the exception :

```
using (var nhr = new NHibernateRepository())
{
    this.Departments = nhr.GetAll<Departments>().Select(x => new SelectListItem 
        {
            Text = x.Departmentdescription, Value = x.Id.ToString()
        });
}
```

Above will bring up to following and threw an exception :

```
public NHibernateRepository()
{
    if (sessionFactory == null)
    {
        config = new Configuration();
        config.Configure();
        config.AddAssembly(typeof(NHibernateRepository).Assembly);
        sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    Session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();
    Rollback = false;
}
```

---

The above is working fine in Test project :

```
using (var nhr = new NHibernateRepository())
{
    var DeptList = nhr.GetAll<Departments>();
}
```

---

Following is the hibernate.cfg.xml file placed in NHibernateRepository project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">  
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Apart from above this project is having all dlls required for NHibernate.

In Test project there is no special configuration settings just we add reference of Repository project and other assemblies required for this and its working fine.

The same has been maintained in MVC3 application project.

Any help in this regard is most appreciable.

Regards

Comment: @Bertrand - thanks a lot to make it formatted. I really wanted to do that but was not able to do.

Comment: nunit and web apps tend to read configuration files differently.  Please provide more information about how your NHibernate configuration is setup (which file(s) is it in, what values are there, etc.).

Comment: @Michael - Updated the original question with more details.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I resolved the issue. There was a silly mistake from my end :( Made hbm files as Embed and all working fine :)

Comment: As above, I found and notified about the solution, I am marking this question as closed. Ah! I tried to mark it as closed but I did not find any valid option asked from closure window. I request to moderators please close this question

Comment: Fill an answer with the solution you found and mark that answer as "accepted".  That is the way to "close" the question (technically "closing a question" is something different that you don't actually want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Michael - I am closing this thread by supplying following answer, I have found during my reasearch.

There are two things we need to do for the proper solution;

1. If using XML files we need to set them as Embedded in properties
2. If not using xml files - we need to make the compiled

To set above just select file name from solution explorere and press F4 or See property window by Right clicking on the file name and then property link.

Thanks everyone - who answered for the above question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will address your current issues, but I do have a few recommendations. First, implement session-per-request session management, either in your `Global.asax` or (my preference) via an HttpModule. Here's a simple example:

```
public class NHHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += ApplicationEndRequest;
        context.BeginRequest += ApplicationBeginRequest;
    }

    public void ApplicationBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(SessionFactory.GetNewSession());
    }

    public void ApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentSession = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory.GetSessionFactory());
        currentSession.Close();
        currentSession.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Note that this also binds the current session context during the request management.

Also, ensure that you're setting the proper session context. Tests should probably use the `thread` context, but web applications should use the `web` context. I personally configure this via Fluent NHibernate, but I believe in the XML config files it would appear as:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
```

Again, I generally configure with FNH, so verify that.

Comment: thanks for your reply but we are getting before creation of sessionfactory, please refer to complete question and snippet.

Comment: Which line is line 33 in your repository code (so we can know exactly where the error is thrown)?

Comment: Line#33 contains :    config.Configure();

Comment: I suspect this has to do with where the config file is. If you don't have a config file *inside your web app* it likely won't work. If your repository project is a class library, you're going to need to put that config in the web project. Or you can put it in your web.config as described here: http://bradhe.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/migrating-nhibernate-configuration-in-to-web-config/

Comment: Thanks Josh - the same config and same structure is working fine with asp.net project but its throwing issues with mvc3 project only.